# Getting access violation error in wmp.dll when assigning property of WMPLib_TLB.TWindowsMediaPlayer

Tags: delphi

I started getting this error since November 2019. Windows security updates are to blame. The bug was caught on Windows 7 and 10. Any ideas how to fix it?

```
compiled with      : Delphi 10.2 Tokyo
madExcept version  : 4.0.18
callstack crc      : $78649ba9, $ab93b801, $94e2a1f8
exception number   : 1
exception class    : EAccessViolation
exception message  : Access violation at address 78649BA9 in module 'wmp.dll'. Read of address 00000008

ClntMainThread ($3e90):
78649ba9 +000 wmp.dll
76c8e79b +01b oleaut32.dll                        VariantClear
010df1b2 +0ca Clnt.exe Vcl.OleCtrls               TOleControl.CreateControl
010e0443 +01b Clnt.exe Vcl.OleCtrls               TOleControl.GetOleObject
01fbb0e5 +021 Clnt.exe WMPLib_TLB        7917  +1 DoCreate
01fbb15c +014 Clnt.exe WMPLib_TLB        7921  +1 TWindowsMediaPlayer.CreateControl
01fbb177 +00f Clnt.exe WMPLib_TLB        7926  +1 TWindowsMediaPlayer.GetControlInterface
01fbb226 +02e Clnt.exe WMPLib_TLB        7937  +1 TWindowsMediaPlayer.Get_settings
01fbc2e2 +15e Clnt.exe frVideoPlayer      107 +28 TVideoPlayerFrame.CreateMediaPlayer
```

This is the code. `Self` is a `TFrame`:

```
WMPlayer := TWindowsMediaPlayer.Create(Self);
FWMPlayer.Align := alClient; 
FWMPlayer.Parent := Self; 
if Assigned(FWMPlayer.settings) then //<- line 107 of the callstack
  FWMPlayer.settings.autoStart := False;
```

Comment: An Access Violation near address `$00000000` (in your case, `$00000008`) means that a `nil` pointer is being accessed. You will have to debug into the code to find out where that `nil` pointer is being used exactly.

Comment: Try adding `Assert(FWMP.Settings <> Nil)` before your `FWMPlayer.settings ...` line

Comment: @MartynA ...and make sure assertions are ON.

Comment: @J...  Indeed, an easily-overlooked point, as I have just demonstrated.

Comment: I have just added Assigned(FWMPlayer.settings) and got the same error. @RemyLebeau